# Gaps between intutionistic and classical arithmetic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory, constructive-mathematics

Let $\mathrm{I}\Sigma_n$ stand for the classical theory of Robinson arithmetic + bounded induction + induction on $\Sigma_n$ formulas. Let $\mathrm{CI}\Sigma_n$ stand for the intuitionistic theory of the same axioms and finally also assume that all axioms of Robinson arithmetic are given in a constructively viable form.

Then, is there any $n$ and any formula $\varphi$ such that
$$
\mathrm{I}\Sigma_{n-1} \not\vdash \varphi, \\
\mathrm{I}\Sigma_n \vdash \varphi, \\
\mathrm{CI}\Sigma_n \not\vdash \varphi, \\
\mathrm{CI}\Sigma_{n+1} \vdash \varphi?
$$
The first condition is required to make the question nontrivial, otherwise, $\varphi \vee \neg \varphi$ for $\varphi$ provable in $\mathrm{CI}\Sigma_{n+1}$ but not in $\mathrm{CI}\Sigma_{n}$ would be an example.